# What is the behaviour that takes a class type and links it to what describes it, without any explicit imports?

Tags: java, object, behavior

First, I'm not sure if my question is well phrased, so if someone could help me phrase it so it's findable by others in the future, comments are welcome.

I have the following bit of code:

```
@Override
public void update(float deltaTime){
    //getGraphics returns a Graphics object
    //it inherits from ? can access the AndroidGraphics class because of ?
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    Assets.splash = g.newImage("splash.jpg", ImageFormat.RGB565);

    game.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(game));
}
```

Everything works right(I didn't write it) but nothing ever imports AndroidGraphics that contains the methods attached to the graphic type... everything imports instead the interface that is implemented in AndroidGraphics (which is Graphics). How is that link made, why is it feasible and how is that behavior called?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstraction.

The notion that you can use an object that implements the Graphics interface, without ever knowing, or needing to know, that the implementation is android specific - that its an instance of AndroidGraphics.

The AndroidGraphics class, by implementing the Graphics interface, effectively says 'Whatever contract is implied by that interface, I will fulfill', so clients who need the functionality offered by Graphics dont need to know the type of the class fulfilling tht contract, merely that they do.

Answer (score 0):

It is called [using package members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html). You didn't need to import it because the package argument at the start of your file implicitly imported it without requiring you to use "import".

Comment: Not exactly, but it could have been, I'm keeping this to help out other newbies who might wonder, through the same question, why package members are included without any implicit imports.